# How to use an interface in an interface

Tags: c#, interface

I want to create an interface which can handle multiple other object of one interface.

I tried using the interface in the interface and using an object in the new class.

```
public interface IObject
{
    double Value { get; set; }
}

public class FirstObject: IObject
{
    double Value { get; set; }
}

public class SecondObject: IObject
{
    string Titel { get; set; }
    double Value { get; set; }
}

public interface ICollection
{
    IObject[] Values { get; set; }
}

public class Collection: ICollection
{
    SecondObject[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

Now I get the error, that my `Collection` doesn't implement the `IObject[] Values` member.

I thought when I use an object (`SecondObject`) which is implementing from the interface `IObject` the `Collection` should handle this.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: The Collection class does not implement the Value property of the ICollection Interface because it is not of the type IObject[].If you want to have explicit implementations for concrete Types you should use a generic implementation for Collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be off better here using generics:

```
public interface ICollection<T> where T : IObject
{
    T[] Values { get; set; }
}

public class Collection : ICollection<SecondObject>
{
    public SecondObject[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

The reason that it doesn't work now, is that the signature should match exactly. That means the `Values` should be an array of `IObject`, which it isn't. Using generics you can solve this, while keeping the type constraint.

A second, but inadvisable solution would be using an explicit interface implementation:

```
public SecondObject[] Values { get; set; }

IObject[] ICollection.Values
{
    get
    {
        return this.Values;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Values = value?.Cast<SecondObject>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah.. totally forgot about the generics.. thank you so much!

Comment: As someone who has started to wrap his mind around using generics a lot more in their code, this answer was beautiful and gave me an actual solid example as to why it was useful.